# How to resolve #Name error in CSV

Tags: java, android, arrays, excel, csv

On inserting a data containing "-" sign to CSV, it throws #Name error, for eg:

```
-QXyUfiP39c
```

on open the excel sheet will get,

[image]

Is there way to suppress error.

Comment: You will have the same problem if anything starts with a **+** sign as well. Excel is interpreting **QXyUfiP39c** as a named range which does not exist. Preface the value with a single quote (e.g. `'`) or import the CSV properly and designate the column as text.

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me how can i make the column as text?. can you tell me steps please. i have no knowledge about CSV

Comment: You can start by recording yourself using the Data, Get External Data, From Text command. On the Step 3 of 3 property page, there is an option to select any column and mark it as Text (or something else like specific date or discard altogether). To code it fully, use the [Workbooks.OpenText method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837097.aspx).